# Google Maps traffic dataset, for academic research

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

Is it possible to get a dataset of google maps that contain time, localisation and the traffic ? I only plan on using this data for my academic research.

Answer (score 0):

- The short answer in terms of **Open Data** is currently no, unfortunately.
- Although [this answer](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/11588291/can-traffic-data-be-visuaulized-over-time?hl=en) on Google Maps help is a few years old it doesn't appear to have changed, see [SO answer updated May 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600656/access-googles-traffic-data-through-a-web-service)

### So What About Other Options?

##### Using Google Maps

- If you are set on using Google Maps you can use their API to make calls for real time data and build the specific traffic data you would like for you research.
- This would only work from the point in time you start collecting forward as it is real time data.
- [Traffic layer API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic#maps_layer_traffic-javascript)
- Cost: $200 free per month = approx 29 000 API calls [from here](https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/)
- [Time in traffic](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/distance-matrix#distance-matrix-advanced) API calls can get specific traffic times for a specific route
- Cost: [$10.00 per 1,000 calls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing#distance-matrix-advanced)

##### Third Party Tools Using Google Maps

- There are third party tools that can be used to extract data from Google Maps.
- Some have a free tier for certain usage limits
- As an example (only through a quick search, there are probably other similar services) [OutScraper](https://outscraper.com/google-maps-traffic-extractor/):

> Scrape all the traffic data since 2001. Historical data is available for all countries covered by Google Maps.

- Cost: [500 free records. $1 per 1000 after](https://outscraper.com/pricing/)

##### HERE Map Service

- [Second answer in SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600656/access-googles-traffic-data-through-a-web-service)
- Cost: 1000 free calls daily [See here](https://www.here.com/get-started/pricing). Typically 0.66 Euros per 1,000 calls above this

##### OpenStreetMap

- Open-source mapping project, is maintained by a community of volunteers
- Traffic data is **not** real time and only an approximation "to describe how congested a road is usually." [See here](https://www.google.com/search?q=openstreetmap%20traffic&client=firefox-b-d&sca_esv=561536078&sxsrf=AB5stBiGJ4mKiaT_SQJq8Sq9kQ_yalzlBA%3A1693460956920&ei=3CnwZJLiN4CrhbIPwKmfwAg&ved=0ahUKEwiSwJzWmYaBAxWAVUEAHcDUB4gQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=openstreetmap%20traffic&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiFW9wZW5zdHJlZXRtYXAgdHJhZmZpYzIIEAAYigUYkQIyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIEEAAYHjIIEAAYBxgeGA8yDxAAGAgYBxgeGA8Y8QQYCjIIEAAYCBgeGA9I3BZQggxY3xVwAngBkAEAmAFMoAHQA6oBATe4AQPIAQD4AQHCAgoQABhHGNYEGLADwgINEAAYRxjWBBjJAxiwA8ICCxAAGIoFGJIDGLADwgIIEAAYBxgeGArCAg0QABgHGB4YDxjxBBgKwgIGEAAYBxgewgIIEAAYCBgHGB7CAgcQIxiwAhgnwgIKEAAYCBgeGA0YCsICDxAAGAgYHhgNGA8Y8QQYCsICCBAAGAgYHhgNwgIHEAAYDRiABMICBhAAGB4YDcICChAAGAgYHhgNGA_iAwQYACBBiAYBkAYJ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)
- This option counts traffic as not only cars but also walking. See [What Counts As Traffic](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:traffic:hourly) section of the link

### Summary

- Currently no Open Data set
- There may be other options out there that suit your research needs.
- Depending on the specifics of your research you may be able to come under free tiers of non Open Data services or if you only need general data OpenStreetMaps may be useful as a free option